# Is it required/recommended to remove Trace.beginSection endSection API from release variant?

Tags: android, performance, systrace

I just found that using [Trace](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Trace).beginSection can help troubleshoot performance issues while using systrace tool.
The documentation states "This tracing mechanism is independent of the method tracing mechanism offered by Debug#startMethodTracing"

But just like debug logs, do we need to comment/remove Trace API before releasing the app. Or is it allowed/benign to leave Trace API invocations in release code?

[Preparing for release](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing#turn-off-logging-and-debugging) checklist does not mention anything about trace API.

But I am doubtful because there are other methods like Trace.setCounter which can be used to log debug info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I remove the traces when I'm done with them but Google leaves it in for some of the most basic building blocks like `RecyclerView` so it's probably fine.

Here's an example from the `RecyclerView` source:

```java
// androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

void consumePendingUpdateOperations() {
    if (!mFirstLayoutComplete || mDataSetHasChangedAfterLayout) {
        TraceCompat.beginSection(TRACE_ON_DATA_SET_CHANGE_LAYOUT_TAG);
        dispatchLayout();
        TraceCompat.endSection();
        return;
    }
    if (!mAdapterHelper.hasPendingUpdates()) {
        return;
    }
                                                                                            
    // if it is only an item change (no add-remove-notifyDataSetChanged) we can check if any
    // of the visible items is affected and if not, just ignore the change.
    if (mAdapterHelper.hasAnyUpdateTypes(AdapterHelper.UpdateOp.UPDATE) && !mAdapterHelper
            .hasAnyUpdateTypes(AdapterHelper.UpdateOp.ADD | AdapterHelper.UpdateOp.REMOVE
                    | AdapterHelper.UpdateOp.MOVE)) {
        TraceCompat.beginSection(TRACE_HANDLE_ADAPTER_UPDATES_TAG);
        startInterceptRequestLayout();
        onEnterLayoutOrScroll();
        mAdapterHelper.preProcess();
        if (!mLayoutWasDefered) {
            if (hasUpdatedView()) {
                dispatchLayout();
            } else {
                // no need to layout, clean state
                mAdapterHelper.consumePostponedUpdates();
            }
        }
        stopInterceptRequestLayout(true);
        onExitLayoutOrScroll();
        TraceCompat.endSection();
    } else if (mAdapterHelper.hasPendingUpdates()) {
        TraceCompat.beginSection(TRACE_ON_DATA_SET_CHANGE_LAYOUT_TAG);
        dispatchLayout();
        TraceCompat.endSection();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's okay to leave them in but do not leave any confidential information because it will be exposed to anyone profiling the app.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).